# Generate pages with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, frameworks

I'm working in a company where we are creating a web app, and we are moving all the legacy Yii PHP controllers to a more dynamic style.

Instead of generate HTML with PHP, the app it's moving to ask data to the java private API and receive JSON to generate HTML elements with Javascript, but there still are elements generated in the PHP code.

My question is: is it viable to use the server code (php, ruby, java...) just to generate some data in json and then create everything via javascript once it's received? (maybe everything but body, head tags :P)

Pros? cons?

If it's not a bad idea, is there any tips? Frameworks (like dust.js, backbone...) advices?

Why should I continue with this idea or why get away from it?

**Edit:**
Example:

A php generated page (from Yii framework using MVC as said - so not mixing backend and frontend) with the basic information like page header, side menu, footer, and some content without functionality. Once this page is received, the js takes control and adds extra functionality, right?

The other point is:
The same page but PHP not rendering anything but `<html><body></body></html>` (just the basic stuff, maybe something more like including js files, some headers... you know, the minimum needed) AND setting some javascript variables using JSON objects, with all the information needed by javascript to render the header, menu, body, etc.
So the pattern will be close to the one-page design by js (as backbone, angular.js, etc.).

Comment: You're going to get mostly opinionated responses on this, and with that said, personally, I prefer to do most of my stuff server side, and only have js update the ui after initial load.

Comment: Looking what you've said you are looking for ajax?

Comment: @mituw16 seems right, this seems like it will draw a lot of opinion and specualtion, although ... wth are talking about?!? Your question is very confusing. Why do you have backend code writing front end elements? `java private API`??? Are you switching to jsnode server? Is this sight supposed to be MVCVM, MVC, MVP, or just straight board coding? Like maybe include a bit more detail on what your converting `FROM` and `TO`. Because your basic explanation just leaves me confused as all get out and i'm sure i'm not the only one.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was clear enough.example added to the main text